# How to assign the data to mData from fnRender return value

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am using DataTable with google map. I getting latitude and longitude from server side json. Here i have changing to address and that address is assigned to DataTable data(TD). BUt it gives error.

```
var geocoder;
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var DataTable = $('#DataTable').dataTable({

            "sAjaxSource": "php/totalDevices.php",
            "aoColumns": [{
                "mData": "name",
                "sTitle": "User Name"
            }, {
                "mData": "managerName"
            }, {
                "mData": "imei"
            }, {
                "mData": "email"
            }, {
                "mDataProp": null,
                "mData": null,
                "fnRender":function ( obj ) {
                    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(obj.aData['latitude'], obj.aData['longitude']);
                    geocoder.geocode({
                        'latLng': latlng
                    }, function (results, status) {
                        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                            if (results[0]) {
                                var address = results[0].formatted_address;
                                console.log(address);
                                return address;
                                //callback(address);
                            } else {
                                alert('No results found');
                            }
                        } else {
                            alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
                        }
                    });
                    //return getAddress(obj.aData['latitude'],obj.aData['longitude']);
                },

            }],

        });
```

Comment: Which error do you get?

Comment: It shows undefined . I dont know how to get return value from address. and That geocode fun is async.

Comment: What if you rearrange the code and call `var DataTable = $('#DataTable').dataTable({...` from the success part of `geocode()` if you get valid address?

Comment: I am not able to rearrange code. because i getting the value by the help of object in dataTable fnRender()